# How can i optimize this query to improve performance?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a wordpress website using advanced custom fields and the repeater plugin.  I've managed to put this query together after re-organizing my data using the repeater plugin.  The query below is fired off when a link on a page is clicked and via ajax the results are loaded into a floating window (just a div using absolute positioning).  The problem I have is typically the first time I click a link the results sometimes take 2-4 seconds to show.  After the first click, the results seem to load faster, but even that is inconsistent.  Sometimes its fast and sometimes its slow.

In Chrome, when I open the console under the Network tab, I see it waiting between 650ms to 4.02secs.  Pretty drastic results.

From what I have read, it is not ajax that is causing it to load slow.  It is most likely something on the backend.  We are running the latest version of Wordpress and MySQL 5.7 I think.  When i go to the subpage directly, the results seem to appear very fast.  If someone has a suggestion how i can improve the speed of the ajax results appearing, I'm open to suggestions.

I'm not querying a large amount of data either. My dataset is pretty small, less than 100 total records.  This should be pretty easy and fast too.

$stateloc variable in the query is the state abbreviation that i pass via query string to the subpage that loads in the floating window.  Here is the query that is on the subpage.

```
 $rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
    JOIN $wpdb->postmeta on $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'plfmaps'
                    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
                    AND meta_key LIKE '%s'
        AND meta_value = %s
        ",
        'locations_%_state', // meta_name: $ParentName_$RowNumber_$ChildName
        "$stateloc" // meta_value: 'type_3' for example
    ));
```

I am using jquery 1.10.2.

Here is the ajax call I am using on the primary page.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){


$j( ".statetips" ).click(function(e) {

   var statewindow = e.target.id;
   console.log(statewindow);

$j.ajax({
  url: '/development-map/locations/',
  localCache: true,
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'stateloc='+statewindow,
  beforeSend:function(){
    // this is where we append a loading image
    $j('#statelocinfo').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
  },
  success: function(data) {
//called when successful
    $j('#ajax-panel').empty();
    $j('#statelocinfo').html(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {}
});
e.preventDefault(); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I disagree with 'belongs'. This question is fine here, but you are more likely to get a good answer on codereview. This question requires somewhat in-depth knowledge about the backend of wordpress.

Comment: thanks, i posted it over there.

Comment: Actually it belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com